# Why does pthread_cond_wait return if a breakpoint is set with Xcode 9?

Tags: swift, xcode, pthreads

The following swift code should block forever - `pthread_cond_wait` should never return as no one signals it.
When I run it - it blocks as expected.
If I so much as set a breakpoint using Xcode 9 (9.0.1) the execution continues to the `print("hi")` line.
Is this a strange Xcode bug or am I doing something totally wrong?

```
import Foundation

func check(_ ret:Int32){
    if ret != 0 {
        fatalError("Error \(ret)")
    }
}

var cond = pthread_cond_t()
pthread_cond_init(&cond,nil)
var mutex = pthread_mutex_t()
check(pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,nil))
check(pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex))
check(pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex))
print("Hi")
check(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex))
```

Also checked with `pthread_cond_timedwait`, same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_cond_wait` can have [spurious wakeups](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html).  POSIX is very explicit about this:

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the *pthread_cond_timedwait()* or *pthread_cond_wait()* functions may occur. Since the return from *pthread_cond_timedwait()* or *pthread_cond_wait()* does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

It seems that in your environment, running under a debugger makes such wakeups happen, probably due to the extra signals the debugger triggers.  It is certainly annoying if a debugger influences application behavior in such a way, but technically, it is not a bug.

Comment: Thanks! never heard of this, now I know I have some old code that may break :-(

Comment: Note that if you set a breakpoint in Xcode while your process is running, lldb has to interrupt the process, since we have to insert a TRAP to implement the breakpoint and it's not safe to write over the text of a program while the program's using it.  Getting interrupted is one of the things that will pop pthread_cond_wait out of it's wait state.  It would be nice if we had special "interrupt only for the debugger SPT's that don't behave like a normal interrupt mechanism", but we have to use the standard system ways to do this sort of thing, including their side-effects.